# Translation of "excited" without specific thing

Tags: traduction

"This is an exciting time to be part of the company. I'm really excited."

> C'est un moment passionnant de faire partie de l'entreprise. ____

How should "I'm really excited" be translated? There was a [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21435/what-is-the-best-way-to-express-i-am-excited-for-something) about the translation of "excited", but it deals with excitement about a specific thing. I think the suggestions there do not translate "excited" properly in this context, where no particular thing is specified.

- Je suis vraiment content.
- Je suis vraiment ravi.
- Je suis vraiment impatient.
- Je suis vraiment enchanté.
- Je kiffe vraiment.
- Je ne tiens vraiment plus.

I'm wondering if the best option would be

- Je suis vraiment tout excité.

Also, is *moment* the correct translation of "time", or should we use *temps*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific context,

> « **J'ai hâte !** = I can't wait! »

is the way to go.

It should be noted that the literal translation

> « je suis vraiment tout **excité** = I'm really excited »,

as you put it, tends to have strong sexual connotations.

---

I remember answering a similar question a while ago:

[How do I say in French 'I can't wait to see them!' ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19529/how-do-i-say-in-french-i-cant-wait-to-see-them)

Answer (score -3):

On pourrait dire « Je suis vraiment énervé. ».

Comment: Doesn't *énervé* mean "annoying"? It's the opposite of what I want to say here.